# Gesture recogniser does not works on tableView

Tags: objective-c

The tableView was done programatically, and is listen to delegates .

the gestures :

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnTableView:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];



-(void) didTapOnTableView:(UIGestureRecognizer*) recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"ffff");
}
```

does not being called.

Comment: `UITableView` has lots of gesture recognizers I think, why don't you use some delegate methods like `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and set cell selection style as `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` if you don't want to show a touch to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `UITableView` has gesture recognizers of its own and they conflict with the ones you're adding. You can allow simultaneous processing of gesture recognizers by conforming your `UIViewController` subclass to `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` protocol and implementing the following method `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

On the other hand, what you are trying to do is most probably wrong. Try using a `UIButton` object instead of the gesture recognizer, in 99% of the time that'll be enough.

Answer (score 0):

this should be working, unless you are not tapping on the tableview, check is the tableview showing properly, or add break point to check is the gesture recogniser is added

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable multitouch on the view using interface builder or this property `multipleTouchEnabled`.

if thats not what you are looking for you can use the delegate function for receiving touches:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return YES;
}
```

(if you go to the header of this file you can find similar delegates that might help)